# Can I collect utm param of firebase dynamic links from IOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-dynamic-links

Is it impossible to collect utm parameters of firebase dynamic links from IOS?

Currently I am getting the utm param values by traffic_source.source, traffic_source.medium, traffic_source.name from Android.
(I checked it from BigQuery importing data from firebase analytics.)

However, the dynamic link events from IOS doesn't return my utm param, giving only default values.
I am aware that these utm param is also available at event_param.key,
but in order to monitor our user's action, I was hoping the utm values to be filtered like user_property of the event.

Was there a major update from IOS blocking traffic_source data in google analytics?
If so, could there be any possible way to retrieve these utm params except from event_params.key? (In order to filter the events.)